# Error Ambiguo de CristalReports en ASP.net Classic (explícitamente me dice "SIN ERRORES.")

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

tengo un error muy **ambiguo** en un reporte, tengo 2 semanas con este error y no puedo dar con la solución, ya intente arreglar el RPT, también genere un código alterno para ese reporte y tampoco, en los demás formularios funciona a la perfección, pero no veo por donde solucionarlo.

Les comento que tengo "cristal reports for visual studio" y la versión es la 11, no he podido migrar a una versión mas actualizada porque fue una migración completa del framework 1.1 a las 4.0, la empresa donde trabajo me dio el paquete de cristal repots for visual studio y no han querido migrar a una mas reciente por tiempos / dinero.

2 preguntas

> ¿Alguien a tenido este problema anteriormente?

> ¿Cómo solucionar este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Funciona el reporte o no? No queda claro.

Comment: Si funciono el reporte

Answer (score 0):

me voy a responder a mi mismo :)

En los parámetros que le estoy pasando a mi reporte si ven que tiene un icono pequeño de color amarillo? , bueno ese era el problema , les platico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la formula que tenia anteriormente, explícitamente necesito poner las comillas

Antes:

> {Rep.Usuario} = {?pID} and {Rep.Consulta} = {?pConsulta}

Despues:

> {Rep.Usuario} = "{?pID}" and {Rep.Consulta} = "{?pConsulta}"

Eso era todo el problema!